# git issue with updates from pull (ssh) and clone (http)

Tags: git

I have had my git repository for over 1 year and I have been pushing to it and all is well.

Here is the flow:
(local dev by ssh) --> (git repo on hostgator) --> (client cloned by http on hostgator)

I do many commits and push from my local dev to the git repo, and once in while when I think the feature is complete, I update the client by issuing the standard `git pull origin master`.

Until today, I noticed an interesting issue. The issue is that even though my local dev committed the changes, when ever I pull on the client, it doesn't update anything. I did some testing found this pattern.

1) by http clone:
I `git clone http://.../project.git new_project_by_http`, and did `git log`, it shows the latest commit is from a couple days ago.

2) by ssh remote:
I created a new directory (new_project_ssh), `git init`, and `git remote add origin ssh://....`. I did a `git log` and the latest commits from my local dev.

Does anybody know why there is a difference between the two methods? I've tried searching the issue, but have not gotten any luck.

Comment: What do you log in second example if you didn't fetch/pull anything before? Is the remote on your machine or you are hosting it somewhere? In the first case describe server setup (git/apache) in latter contact admins.

Comment: In the second example, I used the same credentials from before.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between the two protocols: a `git pull` with an https or ssh origin will give you *exactly* the same result.

The only difference is in the local client repo current status:

- either you are on the wrong branch and are pulling one which isn't updated
- or you are on no branch at all, which is called detached HEAD: see "[Why did git detach my head?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309)".

Comment: Yes, I totally agree that git pull from http or ssh should give me the same results. I do not have any branches, just HEAD. If I do "git branch -a" only "master" shows up. No other branches.